# How do we remove the contentious border in Morocco?

Tags: here-api, heremaps

The border highlighted in the image below is contended, so users in Morocco can be offended by its display. Is there a way to control the display of this element (and other similar elements such as the "South China Sea")?

[image: Morocco Border]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a geo-political view available by passing a `pview` query string parameter to the API.

For example:

```
https://2.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com
    /maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/normal.day/5/9/21/256/png8
    ?apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}
    &pview=ARG
```

There is [full documentation on the HERE Maps site](https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/dev_guide/topics/geopolitical-views.html).

The difference this makes can be seen in the below example. Note the broken border at the top of the map, compared to the solid border in the second rendering.

Before

[image: Broken Border]

After (Argentina's view)

[image: Solid Border]

You can look up a list of political views using the `pview` [API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/dev_guide/topics/resource-meta-pviews.html)

```
https://{1-4}.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com/maptile/2.1/meta/pviews
    ?apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}
    &{param}={value}
```